# Create Basic Image in Debian

Tags: debian

I am trying to create a basic physical image for the packages installed in Debian. I want to to list the necessary packages and delete the unused ones and create a basic image .

I  need to create a image file to port to my embedded device . Can you please guide me ?

I am trying to follow the below approach :

1. list the packages installed
2. copy all the packages into a folder
3. delete unwanted packages
4. create an image to the folder which contains packages

Can you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Build ?

Comment: ... or would a cloned image of an instralled Debian system work for you?

Comment: I want to create a basic image of the packages running on my embedded device under Debian 9.8. When I want to load on a fresh device I just flash the image. The image will download all the packages and later I can run my software. 

Basically I have the set up ready on my device. 
Debian installed along with necessary packages , SeLinux activated. I want to create an image of this so that I can use it to any fresh device

Comment: Since your target is an embedded device, could you pleae tell us how you plan to apply the image to the device?

Comment: I am thinking i will back up the entire working embedded device to a live USB and store the image. I can use the live USB for other new devices to replicate the working embedded device by mounting it. 

Just want to know how can we create a basic image of the working embedded device( All the contents) and store in USB. Later use the USB to load to new devices.

Comment: Try `partimage`. It's straight forward in use. It does not backup whole disks, partitions only. It only stores used sectors and it compresses. But still use a source partition that is not to large because you cannot deploy partimage images to smaller partitions. Use full size partitions on target device only. If your embedded system is arm using u-boot then there won't be any boot code outside the partition. You may try `clonezilla` instead for full disk images but I don't like it because of its complexity. It uses partimage itself but additionally stores partition table etc.

Comment: Thank you.. I tried installing partimage but its says command not found. i tried apt-get update as well. I edited by source files list but still no luck. Can you help me provide the link which supports in debian 9.8

Comment: usually you should install `partimage` simply by `sudo apt install partimage`. If you want a more detailed answer you have to provide more information about your environment (target hardware, target os ...)